# Maximal Open Set in a Topology

Tags: general-topology

**Definition:** A proper nonempty open subset of $U$ of a topological space $X$ is said to be a ***maximal open set*** if any open set which contains $U$ is $X$ or $U$.

i.e.,

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $U\subseteq X$. Then,

$U$ is a ***maximal open set*** $\iff$ ($\forall U_{1} \subset \tau$ and $U\subset U_{1}): U_{1}=X$ or $U_{1}=U$

***Theorem:*** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and U be a maximal open set.

**1)** Assume that $X-U \subsetneq W$ for all $x\in X-U$ and open neighborhood $W$ of $x$. Then $(X-U)^{\mathrm{o}}=\emptyset$.

**2)** Assume that there exists an open set $W\in\tau$ such that $X-U=W\neq X$. Then $(X-U)^{\mathrm{o}}=X-U$.

I tried to prove the second part:

**Proof: 2)** We have there is an open set $W\in\tau$ such that $X-U=W $. Since $W$ is an open set, $X-U$ is also an open set. Then $(X-U)^{\mathrm{o}}=X-U$.

But honestly, I do not have an idea about the first part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part you can do like this. Assume $(X-U)^\circ\neq\emptyset$. It is an open set by definition. The so is $(X-U)^\circ\cup U$ and this open set is larger than $U$. Since $U$ is maximal the $(X-U)^\circ\cup U=X$. in other words $X-U=(X-U)^\circ$. $X-U$ is open and so a neighborhood for each of its points.  Applying the property for $W=X-U$ you get $X-U\subsetneq X-U$ which is obviously a contradiction.

Comment: How did we apply the property?

Comment: We have found that X-U is open but I do not understand how it helps us?
The property W=X-U belongs the second part

Comment: Since X-U is open in particular for all $x\in X-U$ it is an open neighborhood of $x$. The first part assume that for any of such a neighborhood $W$, $X-U$ is (strictly) included in $W$. Then, since $X-U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ $X-U$ is strictly included in $X-U$ what is not possible. In fact I indeed prove the second part in the proof of the first one. Let me rephrase it : $X-U$  is open and so a neighborhood for each of its points. Let $x\in X-U$ and take the open neighborhood of $x$, $W=X-U$, by assumption on $x$ (the one of the first part), $X-U\subsetneq X-U$

Comment: Now I clearly understand, thank you very much